# Selenium driver.get how can i add modular link?

Tags: python-3.x

I cant add navigate website other URL

```
print('Enter URL:')

input()

URL = "Link" + input + "more"

driver.get(URL)
```

> Type Error: can only concatenate string (not "builtin_function_or_method") to string

This is my problem i think.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this problem by not naming variables after keywords or function names.

```
print('Enter URL:')
my_url = input()
URL = "Link" + my_url + "more"
driver.get(URL)
```